# c++ performance based on object creation

Tags: c++, c++11

I work with legacy C++ that was originally written to compile with C++98. But, we compile now with C++11 (yay!) and try to use the newer compiler features when putting in new or modifying old code. This is a common thing seen in our code:

```
MyObj a = doCalc(); // some calculation result
MyObj b = a; // copy a to b before modifying a
```

My question is this. If I change the above to take advantage of newer object creation techniques, am I making the code perform better? Is there any difference to the compiler? Like this:

```
MyObj b(a); // is this better for performance?
```

Comment: Your second sample does something different to the first. So asking about performance doesn't make sense. Did you mean `MyObj b(a);`?

Comment: And if it is `MyObj b(a);` you could've done that in C++98.

Comment: Yup, sorry, I mistyped it. I'll fix it. But, I guess you answered my question also. Hmm...I must have misunderstood something in C++98. I thought that wasn't possible prior to 11.